# Is it possible to make OpenSSL work with gnutls?

Tags: openssl, libvirt, gnutls, mitmproxy

I have libvirt, one client and one server. Libvirt uses gnutls implementation of tls. I want to use mitmproxy and put in the middle between client and remote server. But mitmproxy uses different implementation of tls - openssl. I read that their certificates and maybe handshake process are not compatible with each other?

Are there any suggestions on which steps should be taken to achieve compatibility or I should just provide for mitmproxy one more implementation of tls layer using gnutls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to make OpenSSL work with gnutls?

No of course not. - Yes of course.

Both do, more or less, exactly the same thing: they are crypto libraries that provide as different implementations support for (the same) cryptographic protocols to OTHER applications.

Openssl doesn't need to and can't use gnutls libraries and vice-versa won't need to happen either.

On the other hand: APPLICATIONS linked to OpenSSL libraries can of course communicate with other applications that are instead linked to GnuTLS, as long as

- both applications  mutually agree and use the SAME PROTOCOL
- the selected protocol is available and implemented correctly in both libraries

> I read that their certificates and maybe handshake process are not compatible with each other?

Uhh, where?

As long as they both implement the protocol correctly there is no a priori reason why you should have compatibility issues.

Comment: here -   https://www.gnutls.org/manual/html_node/Compatibility-with-the-OpenSSL-library.html, but this now seems is related to function calls.

Comment: That is indeed more a warning that GNUtls is not a drop-in replacement at code level. Other compatibility issues such as [this](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1238333) are possible but in general the result of incorrect implementation or different interpretations of the standards